# Grails 2.4RC1 / Mongo DB Plugin / Mongo Db 2.6 / Authenticated

Tags: mongodb, grails, authorization

How do I create / or ensure that an index exists for my domain class using Grails 2.4RC1 / Mongo GORM Plugin and Mongo DB 2.6 in --auth mode: ?

Let's assume:
1) I have a valid user identified with appropriate roles in my Mongo Instance.
2) I am able to authenticate to that user using the connectionString configuration in DataSource.groovy
3) I define in the static mapping { lname index:true } for my Person domain class

I will get an error on startup indicating that my user doesn't have the authority to run the createIndex command. I do not get this error when mongo is not run in --auth mode

I have a work around, which I'll attach to this question, but I would think that it would work as documented.

Comment: I added a JIRA issue for this problem: https://jira.grails.org/browse/GPMONGODB-375

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can address the mongo instance and use the low level api to manage your indices as shown below:

In your Bootstrap.groovy you can add:

```
def mongo

def init = { servletContext ->
   def db = mongo.getDB("yourdbname")
   db.person.ensureIndex([lname: 1, fname:1])
}
```

Not what I would consider the best solution, but it seems to work.